# Add parameter to existing config file if present

Tags: shell-script, sed, configuration, pam

Using a script I want to modify the /etc/pam.d/common-session file based on the existing value:

1. if `session required        pam_mkhomedir.so` exist, then add  `skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022`
2. if it's not present, add entire line `session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022`
3. if it's commented (#), uncomment it (and apply rules 1 and 2)

What would be the simplest way to achieve this using shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution with GNU `sed`. I don't know if it's the simplest, but I've reduced your logic a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(grep "session required        pam_mkhomedir.so" $1) ]]
    then  $(sed -i 's/#\?session required        pam_mkhomedir\.so.*/session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=\/etc\/skel\/ umask=0022/'  $1)
    else $(sed -i '$ a session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022' $1)

fi
```

Change the line that contains `session required        pam_mkhomedir.so` to line `session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022`.
This covers the case when the line is commented (`#\?` zero or one #), as well as if it doesn't have skel and umask options specified.

Else, if there is no such line, append line `session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022` to the end of the file.

You can call the script like `./script.sh /etc/pam.d/common-session` or without parameters if you change `$1` for the file path

Comment: NIce, this is doing what I was looking for. Thank you so much also for the explanations

Comment: It's a pleasure to help :)